# Checking variable arguments for type

Tags: c++

I have the below a function I use for string concatenation, it takes in a variable length set of arguments. I want to check to make sure each element is
a char*. I was looking into using dymanic_cast but it cannot be used for char*.
How should I go about casting the arg?:

```
char* Concatenate(int numStrings, ...)
{
    vector<char*> stringVectorArray;
    va_list vargList;

    if (numStrings > 0 && numStrings < MAX_STRING_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        //Store each of the arguments so we can iterate through them later.
        va_start(vargList, numStrings);
        for (int currIndex = 0; currIndex < numStrings; currIndex++)
        {
            char* item = (char*)(va_arg(vargList, char*));
            if (item == NULL)
            {
                //Error: One of the parameters is not char*.
                va_end(vargList);
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                stringVectorArray.push_back(item);
            }
        }
        va_end(vargList);
    }

    return ConcatenateStrings(stringVectorArray);
}
```

Comment: I think you should use [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Comment: Unless `ConcatenateStrings` returns a static or global buffer, or a dynamically allocated `char *`, this function is doomed for failure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why is it doomed for failure?

Comment: @Katianie It is doomed because you would be returning a pointer to a local variable.  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ahh, good eye. In my case however (I didn't provide ConcatenateStrings so you wouldn't have known) It uses the vector but returns a dynamically allocated char* buffer.

Comment: Then the question becomes who deallocates the memory?  You've now opened yourself up to memory leaks.

Comment: The person using the function is responsible for the de-allocation.

Comment: @Katianie -- Then no one will want to use it.  If you're writing C++ code for others to use, the last thing you want to do is to create code that does not adhere to good resource management, i.e. RAII.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply don't know. There is no well-defined way of knowing what the argument types are for a variable argument list.

You have to trust the caller to get it right: in C, use the `(char*)` notation, in C++ use `reinterpret_cast`.

The variadic templates of C++11 introduce type safety into variable argument lists.

Comment: Interesting, can you provide an example of what you meen by variadic templates of c++11 to do this?

Comment: @user4581301 That doesn't seem to be the same thing Edmund is refering to.

Comment: Edmond used a different name. Read down a few lines and you will find "A template with at least one parameter pack is called a variadic template."

Answer (score 0):

> "cannot be used for char*"

Don't use char* then, use an object which CAN be used with dynamic cast, like std::string or your own class.

Comment: I want to use traditional C strings.

Comment: Then Edmund's answer is the one you want.